# Yocto: use static library of other recipe,

Tags: embedded, yocto

I am new to yocto and I want to use static library and files generated by another recipe.
I can find them in poky/build directory, i.e:

```
./tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/test1/usr/lib64/libtest1.a
```

is there any way to use this static library in another recipe ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Assume that your recipe *test1* is providing `libtest1.a`. Then just add this line:

```
DEPENDS = "test1"
```

to the another recipe and the library will be available in the recipe sysroot during build.

You can find more information in the [official documentation for the DEPENDS variable](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DEPENDS).